# Mysterious light source

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, unreal-5

In 5.0.3, I removed all light objects from the project, including the skylight and any/all lightbulbs. Yet, there are two spots of light in my model, one on the floor and one on a wall. What might be up with that?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a baked lightmap in this level?

Comment: Are you using lumen or lighmass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing can occur with shadows.

Rebuild the lighting to rebuild the lightmaps and shadow maps in lightmass.

If you are running lumen, this is a bug if it occurs when running the game. If it happens in editor after running PIE, moving the viewport "camera" will recalculate the lighting.